# MMDrawerController with Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

in my project i would like to use the MMDrawerController plugin ( https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController ) but i have a problem. In the project i'm using the storyboard so i have read this post http://pulkitgoyal.in/side-drawer-navigation-for-ios/ but the plugin doesn't works.

I have the root view controller that calls another view (the drawer) with a segue and so it use this method (as written in the guide)

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DRAWER_SEGUE"]) {
    MMDrawerController *destinationViewController = (MMDrawerController     *)segue.destinationViewController;

    // Instantitate and set the center view controller.
    UIViewController *centerViewController = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FIRST_TOP_VIEW_CONTROLLER"];
[destinationViewController setCenterViewController: centerViewController];

// Instantiate and set the left drawer controller.
UIViewController *leftDrawerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SIDE_DRAWER_CONTROLLER"];
[destinationViewController setLeftDrawerViewController: leftDrawerViewController];
  }
}
```

When the destionation view is loaded i see only the centerView without the Side drawer controller. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried opening the side view controller on some action on center view controller?

e.g.,

```
- (IBAction)menuTapped:(id)sender {
[self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

this will open up the side drawer for you.

EDIT:
Else simply write the following code in your Center view controller's viewDidLoad,

```
self.mm_drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
self.mm_drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
```

You can change the gesture mode as per your requirement.